# Linear Algebra, Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I do have a problem which I don't know how to start...

Be  $\mathbb R_3[x]$ the space of polynomial functions with $gr≤3$ and an endomorphism

$$T:\mathbb  R_3[x]→\mathbb  R_3[x]$$
$$T(f)(x) = f'(x)$$

Find the matrix of map T in basis {$1,x,x^2,x^3$}, the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

I have exam this friday... and I tried to translate the problem... hope you guys will understand.

Comment: What you have to find is a matrix $M$ such that, if you take $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$ and $M(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)^T=(b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3)^T$, then $f'(x)=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3$. Start from the base vectors. 1 is $1+0x+0x^2+0x^3$, so it becomes $(1,0,0,0)$. Its derivative is 0, so $(0,0,0,0)$. This means that the first column of $M$ must contain 4 zeros. Can you see that? Can you go on from here?

Comment: Something like this I guess:

$T(1)=0$

$T(x)=1$

$T(x^2)=2x$

$T(x^3)=3x^2$

Comment: Exactly. Can you use that to finish the matrix?

Comment: What is $gr$ in this instance?

Comment: $\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 3   \end{matrix}$ if I am not mistaken, this should be the matrix.

Comment: @ElChapo $gr$ should be the degree of a polynomial. It should be if $f$ is a polinomial, $gr(f)$ is the degree of $f$, and $gr\leq3$ means "degree less than 3". Written more formally, it would be "polynomials $p$ such that $gr(p)\leq3$.

Comment: @IndreDan almost. Try $x$. It corresponds to $(0,1,0,0)$, and is mapped to $(1,0,0,0)$. With that matrix, it would be mapped to itself. So we find out those nonzero entries should be one column further to the left.

Comment: \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0   \end{matrix}

Comment: @MickG is it correct?

Comment: Yep, dat's right.

Comment: @MickG
And for the eiganvalues I found $\lambda_1=0;\lambda_2=0;\lambda_3=0;\lambda_4=0$

$$
\begin{vmatrix} -\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -\lambda & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -\lambda & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -\lambda   \end{vmatrix} = 0
$$

Comment: OK. So you have the eigenvalue 0 with algebraic multiplicity 4. What about geometric multiplicity? Can you find eigenvectors? One is easy to see, and I think it is the only one. Turn the eigenvector condition into a system of equations. OK, the only one up to multiplication by a real number :).

Comment: PS consider converting these comments to an answer, so you can accept it. Or you can accept the hint-answer below. This gets the question off the unanswered list. If you decide to post an answer, you may have to wait up to 2 days before the system lets you accept it.

Comment: Btw "translate the problem"? From which language? Just curious ;).

Comment: @MickG
I know this part with eigenvectors when I studied the Jordan form of a matrix... So that part is easy.

$X_1= a \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0   \end{bmatrix}$

From romanian language to english...
And please forgive me but I am new to this forum.

Comment: Don't worry. One thing: avoid column vectors in inline formulas, since they distort the interline spacing. I advise you to use line vectors, and if you need column vectors use $\hphantom{i}^T$ to indicate you mean a column. $\hphantom{i}^T$ means transpose matrix. So the transpose of a row is a column. For matrixes, you can use `\begin{smallmatrix}…\end{smallmatrix}`, in comments and inline. It compresses the matrix.

Comment: @MickG
So a vector is $X_1=a(1,0,0,0)$

For the other one should I leave $a$ untouched or I need to take the value $a=1$ and resolve the equation system? Because I will get something like this if I don't touch $a$.

$X_2=(b,a,0,0)=b(1,0,0,0)+a(0,1,0,0)$. And those are two vectors.

Comment: Wait. To get eigenvectors you need $Mx=0$, where $M$ is the matrix we found and $x$ is a vector. If $x=(x_1,\dotsc,x_4)$, then we get $Mx=(x_2,2x_3,3x_4,0)$. To have that 0, you need $x_2=x_3=x_4=0$, so you are left with $(a,0,0,0)$. Those are the only eigenvectors.

Comment: @MickG

So the function is only $f(x)=a$? Our professor said that we need to determine the auxiliary eigenvectors. Or the problem is solved?

Comment: What do you mean by "auxiliary eigenvectors"? To me the problem is over: we have the matrix, the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors.

Comment: The algebraic multiplicity is 4 and the geometric should be 1 because we have only an $a$.

Comment: @MickG
One more little thing, same problem but:
$$
T(f)(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)
$$
How can I calculate: $T(x)=?$

Comment: Let me see. Set $f(x)=x$. Then $T(f)(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)=x+1-x=1$. So $T(f)=1$.

Comment: @MickG
And for: $x^2$ would be: $T(x^2)=x^2+1-x^2 \;$ or $T(x^2)=(x+1)^2-x^2$ ?
I think is the second one...

Comment: Second one, naturally. It is $f(x+1)$ that you need, not $f(x)+1$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Screenshots**

Since the comments answer the question, I thought I'd post an answer with them before someone thinks of moving the discussion to chat. Tomorrow I'll work on a sum-up.
Here are 4 screenshots with the comments:
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d8X2.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0qLc.jpg)
[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d8X2.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d8X2.jpg)
[[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40HN6.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40HN6.jpg)
[[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfZUA.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfZUA.jpg)

**Sum-up**

*Problem reformulation*. What we have to find is a matrix $M$ such that, if $x$ is the vector representing a polynomial $f(t)$ w.r.t. the given base, then $Mx$ represents $f'(t)$ w.r.t. the same base. Then we will need to find $M$'s eigens.

*Finding $M$*. To find $M$, we compute things on the base. If $f_1(t)\equiv1$, then $f_1'(t)\equiv0$. Now, $f_1$ corresponds to $e_1=(1,0,0,0)$, and it becomes $0$, so $Me_1=0$. Similarly, if $f_2(t)=t$, then $f_2'=f_1$, so $Me_2=e_1$; if $f_3(t)=t^2$, then $f_3'=2f_2$, so $Me_3=2e_2$; if $f_4(t)=t^3$, then $f_4'=3f_3$, so $Me_4=3e_3$. Thus, we find:

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

*The eigenvalues.* As OP knows perfectly, we have to find the characteristic polynomial, and the eigenvalues are the roots of that polynomial. So they are the solutions of:

$$\left|\begin{matrix}
-\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -\lambda & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -\lambda & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -\lambda
\end{matrix}\right|=0$$

But that determinant is just $\lambda^4$, so the only root is 0. Hence we have one eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity 4.

*The eigenvectors*. One eigenvector is easy to see: $f_1$ is an eigenvector. As we noted in finding $M$, $f_1'=0=0f_1$. Up to multiplication by scalars, this is the only eigenvector. That can be seen by setting $Mx=0$. If $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, we find $Mx=(x_2,2x_3,3x_4,0)=0$, which requires $x_3=x_2=x_4=0$. So $x$ is an eigenvector of $M$ iff $x=(a,0,0,0)$.

*Little note*. «Polynomials with $gr\leq3$», if I take it right, would be more formally written as «Polynomials $p(x)$ with $gr(p)\leq3$, where $gr$ (perhaps $\deg$ is more standard?) is the degree of the polynomial.

*Extras*. A couple of extra things. Firstly, OP mentioned «auxiliary eigenvectors» as part of the assignment. I do not know what he means by that. To me, the problem is over as is now. Secondly, if we consider the map $T(f)(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ instead, then $T(f_1)$ is again 0, $T(f_2)$ is again $f_1$, but $T(f_3)(x)=f_3(x+1)-f_3(x)=(x+1)^2-x^2=2x+1=2f_2(x)+f_1(x)$, so $T(f_3)=2f_2+f_1$, $T(f_4)(x)=(x+1)^3-x^3=3x^2+3x+1=3f_3(x)+3f_2(x)+f_1(x)$, so $T(f_4)=3f_3+3f_2+f_1$. Hence, the matrix for $T$ is:

$$M(T)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

**To downvoter**

What is the problem with this post in your opinion?

Comment: Thank you very much! I am in your debt!

Comment: Cu plăcere @IndreDan :).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

Compute the transforms of the basis elements (i.e. take their derivatives) and express them in terms of the basis. This gives you the matrix.